# Magento Credit Memo - Qty to refund problem

Tags: magento-1.7, creditmemo

I've creating a new table in which I capture all order states and statuses.
I've got everything working fine including refunds.
I've run into an issue though! I've put a scenario below so you can see what I mean

Order 001

- Product 1 – qty 4 – price – 20.00
- Product 2 – qty 2 – price – 15.00

If I refund 1 of product 1 a new row will be inserted in the DB as a negative number which is correct. Something along the lines of:-

```
 TableID  Name            Qty          Price
 1        Product1        -1           -20.00
```

If I then want to refund another of product 1, I want the table to look like the following:-

```
TableID  Name            Qty          Price
 1        Product1        -1           -20.00
 2        Product1        -1           -20.00
```

BUT what is actually inserting is this:-

```
TableID  Name            Qty          Price
 1        Product1        -1           -20.00
 2        Product1        -2           -20.00
```

So if we then look to tally up how many refunds occurred against product one it looks like there was three.  Actually there was only two.

I was doing something like :

```
private function _getOrderItemDataXm1($order) {
   $i = array();
   foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
         $i[‘qty’] = $item->getQtyRefunded();
   }
}
```

What this is actually returning is the amount that has already been refunded and the amount that is about to be refunded. 
I just want to return the amount that is about to be refunded as a new row in the DB.

Anyone any ideas? Bit stuck with this

Thanks

Comment: Hi Marius,  You could look up the qty refunded, and then look in your own table for that SKU/Name and deduct the amount?  Thus, you'd end up with the right figure?

Answer (score 1):

So the quickest thing I can suggest is what Douglas has mentioned in the comments. You can look up the number you already have your table and do a simple deduction.

Any other suggestions would need more information. If you are doing your addition in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Item` or one of its events you might be able to hook onto the value before it is saved in the `register` function.

When dealing with `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Item` a call to `$this->getQty` should give you the number that is currently being refunded.